# How to modify text with pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a personal data project in which I want to analyze my poems. I wrote the poems (together with other data about my day) in excel, using line breaks in my poem text.

Now pandas displays the records in the poem column like in the following example:

"The deep yearning\nto learn something about"

The \n symbolizes that I made a line break in Excel.

How do I get rid of these \n in the whole dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through your dataframe columns and use the replace function

```
df['poem'].replace('\n',' ',inplace=True)
```

This line would look at column called "poem" and replace any "\n" with a space (" ")

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: It worked with this line: df['poem'].replace(r'\n',' ', regex=True)